# How do I translate RecordType descriptions?

Tags: record-type, translation

Related: [How to add RecordType translation to managed package?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111023/how-to-add-recordtype-translation-to-managed-package)

I know [how to translate the Name for a RecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm#customFieldTranslation).

How do I translate a RecordType's Description field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation of RecordType Descriptions is by now possible in the [Translation Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The translation of record type descriptions is not currently possible.

[See the Idea on AppExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpeE) for this change.